# VB: Null Error on assign a variable to the return value

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a method here, which returns an object.
I check the returned object for nothing/null and got an object, but if I try to assign this object to a variable I get a Error: "Object is 'Nothing'".
So I don't know why. Could someone direct me?

Here is some pseudo-code, which should demo it:

```
If getObject() Is Nothing Then
    ' Returns false
Else
    Dim myObject As MyObject
    myObject = getObject() 'ERROR: Object is Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Are you sure that calling two times the method _getObject()_ produces the same result?

Comment: Yes, because I've tried it many times in different scenarios. So the error only occurs if I try to assign the object to a variable. Could it be a type missmatch, which occurs only in runtime? But I think it would not cause this Error Message, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
I have to use the "Set" keyword for setting this to the object. So I don't understand the whole background, but it seems to work.

Comment: Set is used in VBA or VB6 apps. Is this code a VBA or VB6?

Comment: If 'Set' is the answer, it is not a VB.NET question

Comment: Yes, it was 'Set' so an VBA question.